# How to search documents from parent node and his children folders in Alfresco using fts

Tags: api, full-text-search, alfresco

I'm trying to find all node of type cm:content inside a folder and his children folder.

I'm using Alfresco Search API :

```
/alfresco/api/-default-/public/search/versions/1/search
```

and this is the query that I'm using :

```
{
  "query": {
    "query":"PARENT:'workspace://SpacesStore/nodeRef' and name:*toto* and TYPE:content"
  },
  "include":["properties"]
}
```

This request is working but give me only the documents inside the parent folder "noderef" and not the documents inside the children folder.

Could someone give me an hintch on how to get all documents from the parent node and his children folders please?

Comment: Do  you have the qname path of that node? A parent query only does direct children, but by path you can do tree descendants

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks Gagravarr, I just have the noderef and not the qname path. Can I use the nodeRef I’ve got with PATH? I can’t find how to properly use PATh or Qname.